# Custom ConfigurationProvider - Parse xml in dotnet core

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core, xmlserializer

I'm trying to use an existing settings file as a ConfigurationProvider. Then I need to parse the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
   <setParameter name="param1" value="val1" />
   <setParameter name="param2" value="val2  />  
</parameters>
```

I'm having truble understanding how to map this xml to a class. This is what I've tried:

```
[XmlRoot(elementName:"parameters")]
public class Parameters
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<setParameter> parameters { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot]
public class setParameter
{
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

And tried reading it as below:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameters));
 FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(_root+"/SetParameters-Development.xml", FileMode.Open);
 var needThisArray = ((Parameters)ser.Deserialize(myFileStream)).parameters;
```

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml is invalid and thus it cannot be deserialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="param1" value="val1" />
  <setParameter name="param2" value="val2  />  //missing double quote " here 
</parameters>
```

but should be: `<setParameter name="param2" value="val2" />`

btw you can use: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate valid C# classes for you based on your xml.

When i add the quotes it creates me the following model i can use to deserialize:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="setParameter")]
public class SetParameter {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="parameters")]
public class Parameters {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="setParameter")]
    public List<SetParameter> SetParameter { get; set; }
}
```